# Регулярное выражение(поиск и замена в строках)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, регулярное выражение для реализации следующей вещи:
Я в комментариях вставляю смайлы так: текст [smile]smile_name.gif[/smile] текст
Как с текста выбрать смайлы, которые стоят между тегами [smile] и заменить их на <img>
Например, взять smile_name.gif между тегами [smile][/smile] и заменить его на img src='smiles/smile_name.gif'

Comment: Вы даже не пытались [поискать][1] в гугле? Или всё [найденное][2] вас не устраивает?

   [1]:http://code-igniter.ru/wiki/Markup_helper
   [2]:http://kuikie.com/snippet/90-32/php/strings/php-function-to-convert-bbcode-to-html/

Comment: не устраивает. Можете написать регулярку?

Comment: @Макс Ковалько, конечно могу, только в данном случае - даже не пошевелюсь, потому что вам облом приложить усилие, а я за вас ярмо тянуть не собираюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Держите готовый пример:

> `preg_replace('~\[smile\](.*)\[/smile\]~',
>              'img src="smiles/$1"',
>              '[smile]smile_name.gif[/smile]');`

Answer (score 0):

```
s|\[smile\](.+?)\[\/smile\]|'<img src="smiles/'.$1.'">'|e
```

на похапе переведите сами